# Uniview ip camera video is not playing in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, ip-camera, video-player

When I login to Uniview site using chrome browser to view ip camera videos,  it is showing the plugin is not supproted. But in Internet Explorer it is coming.Which plugin is required to play ip camera videos in chrome?. When I inspected in the error I got netsdkplayer-plugin text. Please help